# How I can add to context menu in windows phone 8 item "share' and "rate app"?

Tags: windows-phone-8, contextmenu

When we tap on phone app appear context menu with items "Pin to start" and "uninstall". How can I add to this context menu in windows phone 8 items "share" and "rate and review" using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking at your side-loaded development app? Then these options are missing.

When you publish your app to the store and download it to your phone these options will be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer the third party controls development vendors.

Telerik:-

http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls/contextmenu.aspx